# MongoDB: Setting up Windows Service

Tags: mongodb

I have just installed MongoDB 2.6 and I am trying to run it as a Windows Service on Windows 8, by following the instructions at http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/.

Here's my directory structure within the C drive:

- `MongoDB` (MongoDB installation)

  - `bin`
- `Project`

  - `DB`
  - `Log`
  - `mongo.conf`
  - `mongod.cfg`

The contents of `mongo.conf` is:

```
storage:
   dbPath: "C:\Project\DB"
```

And the contents of `mongod.cfg` is:

```
logpath="C:\Project\Log\mongo.log"
```

As directed to in the tutorial, from the command line (in administrator mode) I then type:

`"C:\MongoDB\bin\mongod.exe" --config "C:\Project\mongod.cfg" --install`

However, I get an error message:

`SEVERE: Failed global initialization: FileNotOpen Failed to open ""C:\MongoDB\bin\Project\Log\mongo.log""`

Please can somebody explain what I'm doing wrong? I've followed the instructions as dictated in the tutorial (except changed some of the directory names).

I'm also very confused as to the difference between `mongo.conf` and `mongod.cfg`...

Thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I was having a similar problem with Mongo 2.6.3. I was trying to set the log path to `C:\Users\Public\Public Databases\Mongo\log\mongo.log` and the service installer kept responding with `Failed to open ""C:\Program Files\MongoDB 2.6 Standard\bin\Users\Public\Public
Databases\Mongo\log\mongo.log""`.

It started working for me when I stopped quoting the log path in the config file. (i.e. I changed `logpath="C:\Users\Public\Public Databases\Mongo\log\mongo.log"` to `logpath=C:\Users\Public\Public Databases\Mongo\log\mongo.log`).

Comment: Importantly, be sure to run the command prompt with Administrator privileges. This fixed it for me. I use version Mongo 3.4

Answer (score 3):

There is a known issue installing MongoDB 2.6.0 as a Windows service using the `--install` command - see [SERVER-13515](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13515). A fix has been committed for the MongoDB 2.6.1 release.

As a workaround, 
I've provided [instructions on how to install the service manually](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13515?focusedCommentId=544367&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-544367) on that SERVER issue.

The short version is:

- open an Administrator cmd prompt
- make directories for your database and log files
- create a configuration file
- create the service definition, similar to:

  ```
  sc create MongoDB binPath= "\"C:\Program Files\MongoDB 2.6 Standard\bin\mongod.exe\" --service --config=\"C:\Program Files\MongoDB 2.6 Standard\mongod.cfg\"" DisplayName= "MongoDB 2.6 Standard" start= "auto"
  ```
- start the MongoDB service

  ```
  net start MongoDB
  ```

For full instructions please refer to [SERVER-13515](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13515?focusedCommentId=544367&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-544367%5d).

> I'm also very confused as to the difference between mongo.conf and mongod.cfg

The MongoDB server doesn't care about the name/extension of the file you specify with `--config` (as long as the file can be read). Your confusion on the format is because the `mongo.conf` example uses the new [YAML config file format](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/) supported by MongoDB 2.6+, while `mongod.cfg` uses the older format supported by 2.6 as well as earlier versions.

I used the older `mongod.cfg` format in my workaround example, as technically someone could adapt these instructions to manually create a service definition for MongoDB 2.4 as well.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem not only when installing as a Windows service but also when running "mongodb.exe" file. I tried to remove double quote (") characters but the error was still there:

2014-08-16T14:14:49.166Z SEVERE: Failed global initialization: FileNotOpen Failed to open "D:\MongoDB\log\mongo.log"

Please note that I was using config file in new YAML format. I had no problem when using the old format. I tried several ways on the new YAML configuration file and finally I found that it doesn't accept the absolute path. Just change to relative path and it works like a charm!

```
My folder structure is:
MongoDB\
   bin\
   data\
   log\
```

Here is my YAML configuration file that works on the build MongoDB 2.6.4 - Windows 64 bit version, installed on my Windows 7 - Professional x64:

```
systemLog:
   timeStampFormat: iso8601-utc
   destination: file
   path: ..\log\mongo.log
   quiet: false
   logAppend: true
net:
   bindIp: 127.0.0.1
   port: 27017
storage:
   dbPath: ..\data
   directoryPerDB: true
   journal:
      enabled: true
```

Comment: Just for the record: While a path with ".." or starting with "\" works when run from the prompt, they are broken when run as a service. This mistake took some time to debug because it was not being logged (what found the error was running "mongod.exe --config c:\mongodb\mongodb.conf --service" by hand).

Answer (score 1):

I tried a lot of things, in the end I had to remove config file and pass dbpath and logpath settings directly. Following command worked for me:-

C:>mongod --dbpath d:\mongodb\data --logpath d:\mongodb\logs\mongo.log --instal
l --serviceName MongoDB --serviceDisplayName MongoDB

Comment: C:>mongod --dbpath d:\mongodb\data --logpath d:\mongodb\logs\mongo.log --install --serviceName MongoDB --serviceDisplayName MongoDB

Answer (score 0):

There is a JIRA on that topic for the last version of MongoDB and a workaround too. A solution is to install a previous version then install the service ans re-use the last version of the driver.
Hope this helps !

Comment: Can you link to the Jira ticket?

Answer (score 0):

@Stennie 's answer, as well as the manual service installation instructions on the mongoDB site were adequate for me. One thing to note though, is that the quoted items in the instructions need double backslashes (\\) in order to work correctly. Probably obvious to most developers, but I had it slip my mind, and the error response was simply that the service fails to start up. Also, be wary of the spaces after the equals signs.

```
sc.exe create MongoDB binPath= "\"C:\\Program Files\\MongoDB 2.6 Standard\\bin\\mongod.exe\" --service --config=\"C:\\Program Files\\MongoDB 2.6 Standard\\mongod.cfg\"" DisplayName= "MongoDB 2.6 Standard" start= "auto"
```

Answer (score 0):

Observing your error log, it's passing two "s instead of one. Omit one(edit your config file content and remove "s) and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when you have error like : "Failed global initialization: FileNotOpen Failed to open .../mongodb.log", if you have log file you can delete it and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Stop MongoDB from `Windows Services` and then try again. It worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

My previous `logpath=c:\programfiles\......`
the alternative is `logpath="c:\program files\......"`
it works

I think the reason is that the system must visit the log file through `c:\program files\......`, but there comes error when I write `logpath=c:\program files\......`because there is a space between program and files. Then I add `""`, and it works. I hope it helps.